# Why authors said that "their behavior for smaller timesteps is known to produce unnatural behaviors" in their paper

Tags: flow-project

In the paper "Flow: Architecture and Benchmarking for
Reinforcement Learning in Traffic Control", the authors said that "SUMO’scar following models are calibrated for a simulation timestep
of 1.0 seconds, and their behavior for smaller timesteps is
known to produce unnatural behaviors". However, I cannot understand why it will produce unnatural behaviors.

I have read the reference that the authors cited, "(2016) Simulation/basic definition. [Online]. Available: http://sumo.dlr.
de/wiki/Simulation/Basic Definition#Defining the Time Step Length".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, guess the 1.0 second is related to human's reaction time. If the timestep is less than 1.0 seconds, it might be unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

for a good answer to this question I recommend directly emailing the corresponding author of that paper! This is more of a general question than a software question and may require a substantive conversation. Hope that helps! It does have to do with what Pao Raw mentioned above.